# What is the ratio of repacked exceptions in PHP being dropped by most logging mechanisms? How do you handle this information loss?

Tags: php, exception, logging, sentry

I have a Drupal site backed up by Sentry.io for logging errors. When I execute the following snippet:

```
$exceptionOrigin = new \Exception("The originating fault");
$exceptionRepack = new \Exception("My repacked abstraction", 0, $exceptionOrigin);
throw $exceptionRepack;
```

neither the logger in Drupal, nor the sentry.io drop any single notice that there was a chain of previous throwables (of length 1 in this case) attached to the logged exception. As far as I remember, xdebug also generates output for only the top most exception. Only the PHP-CLI output (also `__toString()`) offers both.

What is the ratio for ignoring this native feature? To me, it makes perfect sense, to repack an exception leaving 3rd party library. For monitoring, messaging, the abstraction is great. But for debugging, inspecting the original exception is often necessary.

When there is no support for the industry for a feature, it effectively means, the feature is dead.

I am attempting to developing a typed exception library based on mathematical notions. I find the concept of repacked exceptions relevant, but the industry seems not interested in supporting it -- intentionally, I assume.

Does anyone know a ratio for this? How do you handle this situation?

Comment: I would bet that these services have ways of configuring the output to include previous exceptions